# Window's Authentication to access server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I've got a project, which I've configured my application to use Window's authentication.  All other forms of connection were disabled, they have to be part of our domain to connect to this application.  The problem though, some users, though apart of the domain do not have access to the application.  They receive the following generic 401 error specified in Internet Information System.

> 401 Unauthorized Access, access denied.

The project solution has the following:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="ADMembership">
     <providers>
          <add name="ADMembership" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADConnection" connectionUsername="domain/user" connectionPassword="password" />
     </providers>
</membership>
```

The `ADConnection` is a valid Active Directory `connectionString`.  I ensured, when I queried against, the above code is wrapped within my `system.Web`.  Why would some users within the domain correctly login, while others can't?

Additional Notes:

- IIS is configured to try NTLM, then Negotiate.
- Chrome has the domain whitelisted, also NTLM is configured.
- The 401 error will occur after they hit cancel to login, otherwise it infinitely ask for username and password.

Comment: What is the point of the membership provider in the config? It definitely has nothing to do with integrated authentication.

Comment: @WiktorZychla All the documentation mentioned it, what is the documentation for integrated authentication, where it auto logs in as our domain user?

Comment: You possibly misunderstood something, a membership provider is only used together with forms authentication. In case of windows auth, the ntlm/kerberos are used with no explicit configuration.

Comment: Also, verify your config with this checklist http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/06/iis-75-integrated-security-with-no.html

Comment: @WiktorZychla I'll take a look, yeah if I misunderstood I'll want to get the proper documentation to fix my knowledge gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours I found the culprit.

Though the configuration appeared correct:

- Proper permission to directory for *iis_iusrs*.
- Setup Active Directory authentication in the `web.config`.
- Ensured Internet Information System had all disabled, except Window's authentication.

The issue stemmed from the following:

Authenticated Users, that particular role didn't have access to the directory.  So once the user logged in, that role superseded other permissions, not allowing them to access the application.  Once that role had *read* access, then the authentication worked as intended.